# Images wont show up corrently on nav bar

Tags: html, css, image, navbar, css-sprites

Ok so here goes ive spent a good deal of time trying to find a tutorial for this kind of navbar (sprite rollover) i finaly found one that almost works would anyone be able to help me?
the issue that im having is that the images for my buttons arnt showing up in design view at all, they will show up if i take the site live but its not showing the full image, its only showing a small amount of each button behind the text link. Thank you in advance.
here is the code

HTML

```
    <div 
        id="toptop"><img src="css/img/header-top.gif" width="950" height="51">
    </div>

    <div 
        id="topmiddle"><img src="css/img/header-middle.gif" width="950" height="199">
    </div>


    <ul class="navbar">
    <li class="home"><a href="home">index.html</a></li>
    <li class="health"><a href="health">health.html</a></li>
    <li class="workouts"><a href="workouts">workouts.html</a></li>
    <li class="diet"><a href="diet">diet.html</a></li>
    <li class="lifestyle"><a href="lifestyle">lifestyle.html</a></li>
    <li class="news"><a href="news">news.html</a></li>
    <li class="forum"><a href="forum">forum.html</a></li>
    <li class="contact"><a href="contact">contact.html</a></li>
    </ul>       

</body>
```

CSS

```
  .navbar {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 55px;
    width: 950px;
}


.home {
    float: left;
    height: 55px;
    width: 115px;
    position: relative;
}
.health {
    float: left;
    height: 55px;
    width: 120px;
    position: relative;
}
.workouts {
    float: left;
    height: 55px;
    width: 120px;
    position: relative;
}
.diet {
    float: left;
    height: 55px;
    width: 120px;
    position: relative;
}
.lifestyle {
    float: left;
    height: 55px;
    width: 120px;
    position: relative;
}
.news {
    float: left;
    height: 55px;
    width: 120px;
    position: relative;
}
.forum {
    float: left;
    height: 55px;
    width: 120px;
    position: relative;
}
.contact {
    float: left;
    height: 55px;
    width: 115px;
    position: relative;
}
.home a:link {
    background-image: url(img/NavbarSprite.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
.health a:link {
    background-image: url(img/NavbarSprite.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -115px 0px;
}
.workouts a:link {
    background-image: url(img/NavbarSprite.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -235px 0px;
}
.diet a:link {
    background-image: url(img/NavbarSprite.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -355px 0px;
}
.lifestyle a:link {
    background-image: url(img/NavbarSprite.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -475px 0px;
}
.news a:link {
    background-image: url(img/NavbarSprite.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -595px 0px;
}
.forum a:link {
    background-image: url(img/NavbarSprite.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 715px 0px;
}
.contact a:link {
    background-image: url(img/NavbarSprite.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 830px 0px;
}
.home a:hover {
    background-image: url(img/NavbarSprite.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px -55px;
}
.health a:hover {
    background-image: url(img/NavbarSprite.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -115px -55px;
}
.workouts a:hover {
    background-image: url(img/NavbarSprite.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -235px -55px;
}
.diet a:hover {
    background-image: url(img/NavbarSprite.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -355px -55px;
}
.lifestyle a:hover {
    background-image: url(img/NavbarSprite.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -475px -55px;
}
.news a:hover {
    background-image: url(img/NavbarSprite.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -595px -55px;
}
.forum a:hover {
    background-image: url(img/NavbarSprite.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -715px -55px;
}
.contact a:hover {
    background-image: url(img/NavbarSprite.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -830px -55px;
}
.home a:active {
    background-image: url(img/NavbarSprite.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px -110px;
}
.health a:active {
    background-image: url(img/NavbarSprite.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -115px -110px;
}
.workouts a:active {
    background-image: url(img/NavbarSprite.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -235px -110px;
}
.diet a:active {
    background-image: url(img/NavbarSprite.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -355px -110px;
}
.lifestyle a:active {
    background-image: url(img/NavbarSprite.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -475px -110px;
}
.news a:active {
    background-image: url(img/NavbarSprite.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -595px -110px;
}
.forum a:active {
    background-image: url(img/NavbarSprite.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -715px -110px;
}
.contact a:active {
    background-image: url(img/NavbarSprite.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -830px -110px;
}
```

Comment: "arnt", really? Too lazy to write proper English? If you expect others to take the time to answer your question, then why can't you take the time to write properly as a courtesy to them?

Comment: Force of habit, are not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off why not do something like this:

```
<ul class="navbar">
   <li><a href="#">Some link></li>
</ul>
```

And then in the CSS you can style all of them using:

```
.navbar li
{
  float: left;
  height: 55px;
  width: 115px;
  position: relative;
} 
.navbar li a
{
  background-image:"someimage.png";
}
```

Comment: the first and last buttons are different sizes from the rest, the home button and the contact buttion are 115px x 55px and the rest are 120px x 55px.

Comment: then you can use .home{} and place that after the .navbar li styling, it will cascade correctly

Comment: Im rather new to coding but i'll give this a try and get back to you, thanks for your help

Comment: It has worked but its still doing the same thing as befor where its only showing a small amount of the image behind the .html text

Comment: You need to swap the href text with the ext before the </a> closing tag in order for the links to work. You need to add list-style:none; to the .navbar css block in order to have the list display in a row

Comment: And finally add to .navbar li a{} width:100%;

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/ebp9ddjex/                                       here is a link to what i have so far, if you look closely you can see that the color behind the text is part of each button.